# How can I get 'sign in with Google' to work using 'dj_rest_auth'?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, dj-rest-auth

I'm trying to implement Google sign in using `DRF` and `dj_rest_auth`.

I've set up 'django-allauth' with Google as provider and the sign in process works in the web browser.

I need to connect an android app with my backend. I've created API endpoints which will require authentication.

According to the [docs](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#google), `code` is required in order to complete authentication and receive the token.

After doing some research, I found that `code` required by `dj_rest_auth` can be obtained by visiting:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=<YOUR CALLBACK URL>&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=<YOUR CLIENT ID>&scope=openid%20email&access_type=offline
```

However, even after passing `code` returned in the query param (after decoding from URL format), the following error is shown:

```
Error retrieving access token: b'{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Bad Request"\n}'
```

To see if I can log in with a recent `access` token, I signed in with my Google account from the homepage , copied the `access` token from the admin section and submitted it to the endpoint `http://localhost:8000/dj-rest-auth/google/`. I was able to receive the auth token generated by `dj_rest_auth`.

I need help in getting the auth token by providing `code` in the post request.

My code:

```
# urls.py
...
path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
path('dj-rest-auth/google/', home.GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
...
```

```
# views.py

from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/'
    client_class = OAuth2Client
...
```

References:

[Google Social Authentication with dj-rest-auth #220](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/220)

[Minimal example for SPA implementation of social login #147](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/147)

Please help me.

Comment: did you find way to get this working? I am also looking to do similar thing for Flutter app.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create your authentication keys on Google Cloud and add them in settings.py ?

It looks like that for me in settings :

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
"google": {
    # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
    # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
    # credentials, or list them here:
    "APP": {
        "client_id": os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
        "secret": os.environ.get("GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY"),
        "key": ""
    },
    # These are provider-specific settings that can only be
    # listed here:
    "SCOPE": [
        "profile",
        "email",
    ],
    "AUTH_PARAMS": {
        "access_type": "online",
    }
}}
```